# Azure Devops API - how to filter/search by project name?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the GET [project List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and I want to filter out the results by a search query parameters.

I have multiple projects under a certain organization and I want to get back only the projects that start with some 'name' initial. I looked everywhere on the documentation but couldn't find any way doing such a query. Is there a way to narrow down the results?

I saw that some API's have the `?$filter={filter}` query param, but it won't work on projects filtering.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it's **impossible** in this API to filter the results **before** you get them.

You only can filter the projects **after** you get the reulsts with Bash/Powershell etc.

Answer (score 0):

I run into similar issue, except I am trying to filter base on Azure Devops's **Repo** list.
It seems M$ has done a terrible job in providing consistent filters features.
I did notice some of the API does provide `?$filter={filter}` and I found [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) would probably help?
Some of the API provides a different search method in form of search criteria `/commits?searchCriteria.$skip={searchCriteria.$skip}&searchCriteria.$top={searchCriteria.$top}...`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0